# How to display remaining event participants?

Tags: civievent, participants

If you want to display the number of remaining event participants (based on their **role**, too) until an event is fully booked, you could implement the following in EventInfo.tpl:

```
<div class="crm-section event_remaining">
    <div class="label">Participants</div>
        <div class="content">{crmAPI var="ParticipantS" entity="Participant" action="get" role_id="1" sequential="1" event_id=$event.id }
    {if $event.max_participants<=$ParticipantS.count}
        0&nbsp;remaining
    {else}
    {math equation="x - y" x=$event.max_participants y=$ParticipantS.count}&nbsp;remaining
    {/if}
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Guitarman: I'm sure that's very useful, but that isn't a question (and your answer is a comment). You can provide your own answers, but you should phrase a question and then provide an answer to it. Keeping to the convention makes it easier to use.

Comment: You're right, I rephrased this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out: role_id="X" > adjust to your needs.
Tested and working.